# How to speed up Binance coin price parsing?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, binance

I'm trying to create a bot that place multiples orders on Binance and I need a fast coin price parsing.

I'm parsing the code using this code

```
Dim price as decimal       
Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()
    Dim downloadTasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))
    Dim dogebusd = wc1.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=DOGEBUSD")
    downloadTasks.Add(dogebusd)
    Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)

    Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(dogebusd.Result)
    Dim PREZZO As Decimal = CDec(Val((d("price")).ToString))
    
    price = CDec((PREZZO))
    
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

but when the price is dumping or pumping really fast, even a 10 ms or 100ms timer tick is not that efficient.
I wonder if this is the fastest way possible or if I can improve the code.
Thanks

following Jimi suggestions:

```
Dim price As Decimal
Private ReadOnly _timer As New PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))

Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _timer.Tick
    timer1.stop
    Dim dogebusdTask = HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=DOGEBUSD")
    Await dogebusdTask
    Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(dogebusdTask.Result)
    If Decimal.TryParse(d("price"), NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, price) Then
        _timer.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you would always have a latency getting the web site, why not run a script on your server that has a better connection to the site., the parsing will be fast as it get only 2 values, but the website need 346 ms to respond even on a 100 meg line. so as long as you can't get the faster results you will not get any faster response

Comment: hmm i do not have any server actually

Comment: wondering if binance has a GET HTTP Methods that can update my label and if it d be faster

Comment: Server has usually at least gigabit ethernet connections, and a server near the website would be very fast.

Comment: no the website prohibits htto requests

Comment: ok this a part, what do you think about my code? would you improve it?

Comment: i don't see why you double CDec the value, second, test the speed of the json parser maybe another faster methid is available, as there are other json parsor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example, using the .NET 6+ awaitable [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer) and [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-7.0) to parse the resulting stream returned by HttpClient's [GetStreamAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync)

The PeriodicTimer can be quite efficient in contexts like this, since it tries to keep up with the interval you have provided. Since the internal procedure takes time to execute - the `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` takes an undetermined amount of time to execute and return a result - the Timer keeps track of the actual elapsed time and tries to keep ticking steadily (unless the procedure takes more than the specified Interval, then you *skip a beat*, of course)

- Note: as usual, when dealing with Tasks that accept a CancellationToken, you should run this code without a Debugger (`CTRL+F5`) or configure the Debugger to not halt on `TaskCanceledException` or `OperationCanceledException`, otherwise it handles the (ignorable) exception before you do

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text.Json
Imports System.Threading

Private Shared ReadOnly m_Client As New HttpClient()
Private timerCts As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing
Private m_PeriodicTimer As PeriodicTimer = Nothing
Private m_PeriodicTimerInterval As Integer = 500
Private currentPrice As Decimal = 0.0D

Private Async Function StartPriceLookupTimer(token As CancellationToken, timerInterval As Integer) As Task
    If token.IsCancellationRequested Then Return
    Dim lookupAddress = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=DOGEBUSD"
    m_PeriodicTimer = New PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timerInterval))
    Try
        While Await m_PeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(token)
            Dim jsonStream = Await m_Client.GetStreamAsync(lookupAddress, token)
            Try
                Dim prop = (Await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(jsonStream, Nothing, token)).RootElement.GetProperty("price")
                Dim strPrice = prop.GetString()
                If Decimal.TryParse(strPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, currentPrice) Then
                ' Do whatever you need to do with the parsed value
                ' E.g., assign it to a TextBox for presentation, 
                ' using the current Culture format, since strPrice contains the original format
                    [Some TextBox].Text = currentPrice.ToString() ' <= UI Thread here
                End If
            Catch knfex As KeyNotFoundException
                Debug.WriteLine("The JSON property was not found")
            Catch tcex As TaskCanceledException
                Debug.WriteLine("The lookup procedure was canceled")
            End Try
        End While
    Catch tcex As TaskCanceledException
        Debug.WriteLine("The lookup procedure was canceled")
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub StopPriceLookupTimer()
    timerCts?.Cancel()
    m_PeriodicTimer?.Dispose()
    timerCts?.Dispose()
    timerCts = Nothing
End Sub
```

How to start this lookup procedure, calling the `StartPriceLookupTimer()` method?
You could use a Button, making its Click handler async:

```
Private Async Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Click
    If timerCts Is Nothing Then
        timerCts = New CancellationTokenSource()
        Await StartPriceLookupTimer(timerCts.Token, m_PeriodicTimerInterval)
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("Lookup Timer already started")
    End If
End Sub
```

Or make the Form's `Shown` Handler / `OnShown()` method override async and start the procedure when the Form is first presented:

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnShown(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnShown(e)
    timerCts = New CancellationTokenSource()
    Await StartPriceLookupTimer(timerCts.Token, m_PeriodicTimerInterval)
End Sub
```

To stop the lookup procedure, call the `StopPriceLookupTimer()` method when needed, e.g., using another Button or in the `Form.Closed` handler / `OnFormClosed()` override

Comment: I'm speachless.. that's even faster than what the website displays.. Thanks JIMI !!!!! keep rocking

Comment: Jimi just a thing.. Is it possible to migrate the framework project to .net 6+? all I can read online is just about the pro about migrating from .net framework to .net but not how to do it. Do i need to re create the entire design?

Comment: [Overview of porting from .NET Framework to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) -- The main issues you may have, are related to NuGet Packages (and their dependencies, if any) that may not be available for .NET (none of the major tools) and rare tools that are now obsolete in .NET (as WebClient). For the rest, it's mostly the same (i.e., no re-design needed, the .NET Designers are compatible with the .NET Framework's)

Comment: hmm I'm using Binance.net developed by JKorf, but it seems available for .net, maybe I'm wrong.. How Am i supposed to bring the form I've created for .net framework into .net 6+? look [link]https://imgur.com/a/Dbdo2L1

Comment: The Package you've mentioned is available for .NET 7, so no issues there. The migration tool's documentation I've linked, helps to port the Project's style from msbuild to the new `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, including all external dependencies. There's nothing else to do, Forms and Controls are exactly the same (as far as the serializer is concerned). If you want, you can import a Form created in .NET Framework in a .NET 7 Project as it is

Comment: that's perfect, I've just swapped the form files and it works like a charm!
Again, thanks! Was nice to read from you again !!!

Comment: would you suggest me to use the PeriodicTimer also for the other things I'm doing? like check open orders etc [link](https://pastebin.com/fJSyHzEn)

Comment: Why not? It's a Timer. It's awaitable and very simple to use, fits very well in this platform. Remember that it cannot be *shared*. One Timer for each task. Dispose of it when not needed anymore. Create it new (as shown here) if / when necessary. Or use a read-only one if its task doesn't change during its life-time